# Resource Providers Microsfot.Storage Registering

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azureportal

How do we register a Resource Provider? The Microsoft.Storage resource provider stays in registering for 3 hours or so. How long does it take to register? I tried the az cli too, the status says Registering

[image: Struck on Registring]

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it will take 5-15 minutes to complete the register.

But this issue may happen if the service is under heavy load and are usually temporary.

If it's still in registering state for a long time after you click the Refresh button, you'd better [open a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to see the root cause.